# how to use useDate

Tags: javascript

I am new here but many people told me to come and get some answers here , so based on the source code listing shown on the next page, notice that we’re starting with:( the code I did is down below n the bottom )

> A single global array called “timers.”
>
> An IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) called “log”
>
> A function literal called “printFunc” which is a “wrapper” function
>   used to output a string (followed by a “ ”) with “document.write.”
>
> An “onload” event handler called “startMeUp” which we use to
>   initialize 3 sample timers using the “setInterval” method. Remember
>   that “setInterval” requires 2 parameters (a function reference to be
>   called and an interval in milliseconds to define the frequency with
>   which the function will be called). Also remember that “setInterval”
>   returns a unique integer number that can be used to perform a
>   “clearInterval” on a specific timer.
>
> In order to complete the lab, you must add some code to the IIFE
>   starting after line 14.
>
> Return an anonymous function declaration (see Example #3 – newObject
>   in functions.html). Your anonymous function should define a single
>   parameter named caller which represents the particular timer (Timer1,
>   Timer2 etc.).
>
> Within the anonymous function declaration, you will have access to all
>   the parameters and local variables of the parent function. As such, on
>   each invocation:
>
> a. Increment the counter by 1
>   b. Push the name of the caller into the
>   “callerLog” array
>   c. Push the current date/time into the dateTime
>   array (use new Date() to retrieve the date/time).
>   d. Create an output string by concatenating the counter, the last
>   entry in “callerLog” and the last entry in “dateTime.”
>   e. Output the string using the designated output function. Note you
>   may not use “printFunc” directly.
>   f. When the counter exceeds 10, shutdown all the timers using the
>   “clearInterval” method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm like that?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lab 2</title>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

        var timers = [];

        var log = (function (outputFunc) {
            var counter = 0;
            var callerLog = [];
            var dateTime = [];

            // return inner anonymous function
            // your code goes here

            return function (caller){
                callerLog.push("Timer" + [counter])
                counter++;
                var d = new Date();
                dateTime.push(d);
                var output = counter + " " + caller + " " + d;
                outputFunc(output);
                if (counter == 11){
                    stopFunction();
                }
                // return caller;


            }

        })(printFunc);




        function printFunc(output) {
            document.write(output + "<br>");
        }
        // stop the interval
        function stopFunction() {
            timers.forEach(timer => clearInterval(timer));
        }

        function startMeUp() {
            // add each of the timers references to the timers array
            // as part of invoking the log function following each interval
            timers.push(setInterval("log('Timer1')", 1000));
            timers.push(setInterval("log('Timer2')", 1200));
            timers.push(setInterval("log('Timer3')", 1700));
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="startMeUp();">

    </body>
</html>
```

Your line 22:

`printFunc();`

My line 22:

`outputFunc(output);`

Also edited the `stopFunction()` Because you need to clear each interval separately.

Comment: Thank you. I a new here . I just want to undertand how this is going to change the clear interval ? I mean after 11 times I need to stop , but I could understand how ? I mean I did a research I understand that we need a outer and inner funcion to make IIFE and this is good because you get the value after go out of function but when I try to use clear interval I just don get ... Any ideas?

Comment: BTW: If speed really matter you should use a `for()` loop; is a bit faster than `forEach()`